# ASP.NET Event Handlers Not Changing UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I have an instance of a custom business class on a asp.net web forms page (.NET 4.0).  This class has custom events that get thrown.  My web forms page establishes the event handlers for the events before calling the business class.  These event handlers do stuff to the page (set a label's text, change a mulitview, etc.).  My problem is that sometimes, the event handler fires (verified by debugging the code and running through it), but the changes to the UI (setting a label's text) does not show on the page

Here is an simplified example -

```
private void MyMethod()
{
   var myClass = new MyClass();
   myClass.PromptForAdditionalData += OnPromptForMoreData;
   myClass.DoSomethingElse += OnDoSomethingElse;

   myClass.ExecuteMethod();
}

private void OnPromptForMoreData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   label3.Text = "Blah blah blah";
   multiView1.SetActiveView(view1);
}
```

Comment: The code looks weird from ASP.Net stand point. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can't do that.  You need AJAX.  Look at Signalr.

Comment: I am trying to have my asp.net page call a method of a class that may fire 1 of 2 different events.  My page needs to act accordingly depending on what event was thrown.

Comment: SLaks - From what I can tell Signalr deals with Server/Client communication.  I am purely server side.

Comment: @DanAppleyard: No; you're trying to change the client

Comment: Let me clarify something - MyMethod is called on a post back.  When the client gets the response back from the server the label has not changed.  How is this different then having a button's server-side click event changing other UI elements?  That doesn't require AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Other options without AJAX, try to postback or redirect to current page.

This is the link to redirect :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: can you explain what either AJAX or postback/redirect to current page would do to solve my issue?